# How to randomly pair-up elements in a vector? [R]

Tags: r, simulation, sampling, population

I've looked through about 7 different answers, plus searched help files, and no luck (haven't used R in a loooong time, so, I'm pretty rusty).

I have a vector that represents a population of *n* players playing *s* different survival strategies, and I want to randomly pair up each element with another. Originally I tried the code below, but obviously that can't work, since the resulting object has *n* elements, whereas my resulting object should have *n/2*.

```
popsize = 10
nstrats = 3

Population <- sample(1:nstrats, popsize, T)
Opponents <- sample(Population)
Pairings <- cbind(Population, Opponents)
```

I'm trying to do this without a loop, though I'll gladly take any suggestions (especially if using a loop is the only way to do it!)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: 'Pairings <- matrix(Opponents,ncol=2)' gives a matrix of 5 games where column 1 plays column 2 - is that what you need, or do you want the strategies included in the matrix?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Miff! Ideally, the pairing approach would be random: even though the strategies were randomly distributed, the pairings are not, since P1 can never play players 2-5 (they belong to the same column), and it will always be the case that P1 will play P6, and so on.

Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry - meant: Pairings <- matrix(sample(1:popsize),ncol=2) for who plays who, then strategies <- matrix(sample(1:nstrats, popsize, T),ncol=2) for the strategies that they use.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This was really close, but lead to the possibility of players being paired with themselves (i.e., if my vector only had 1 player playing strategy S1, it could be paired with itself, even though this should not happen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you a list of pairings from the Population (it just splits `Population` into pairs):

```
split(Population,rep(1:(popsize/2),each=2))
```

If you want to randomly pair elements of `Population` just shuffle it before you create the pairings:

```
split(sample(Population),rep(1:(popsize/2),each=2))
```

Comment: Thanks, RoyalITS! Would there be a command to do this randomly? I.e., every time I run the command, I get a different set of pairs?

Comment: Sure. I've amended my answer.